# Sorted queries on a large SQL table are slow despite an index exists

Tags: sql, performance, indexing, mariadb, sql-order-by

I have a very large SQL Table (More than 3 mio rows) comment_field_data.

```
    CREATE TABLE `comment_field_data` (
  `cid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comment_type` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL COMMENT 'The ID of the target entity.',
  `langcode` varchar(12) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The ID of the target entity.',
  `pid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The ID of the target entity.',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The ID of the target entity.',
  `subject` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mail` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `homepage` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hostname` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `changed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thread` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `entity_type` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `field_name` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `default_langcode` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`,`langcode`),
  KEY `comment__id__default_langcode__langcode` (`cid`,`default_langcode`,`langcode`),
  KEY `comment_field__comment_type__target_id` (`comment_type`),
  KEY `comment_field__uid__target_id` (`uid`),
  KEY `comment_field__created` (`created`),
  KEY `comment__status_comment_type` (`status`,`comment_type`,`cid`),
  KEY `comment__status_pid` (`pid`,`status`),
  KEY `comment__num_new` (`entity_id`,`entity_type`,`comment_type`,`status`,`created`,`cid`,`thread`(191)),
  KEY `comment__entity_langcode` (`entity_id`,`entity_type`,`comment_type`,`default_langcode`)
)
```

Queries like

```
SELECT entity_id FROM comment_field_data ORDER BY created LIMIT 300
```

perform very poorly (several seconds) - and

```
EXPLAIN SELECT entity_id FROM comment_field_data ORDER BY created LIMIT 300;
+------+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys | key              | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                       |
+------+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | comment_field_data | index | NULL          | comment__num_new | 848     | NULL | 3384043 | Using index; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------+
```

Shows that filesort is used despite an existing index for the created column. I'm not an SQL expert at all and I don't know what ca do to improve this behavior. Can anyone help out?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.12-MariaDB

Comment: I'm commenting rather than answering, because I'm guessing. The table statistics my be out of date. Try looking into https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-table/ Failing that, a single covering index on (created, entity_id) would be a more optimal index any way. I'd also recommend asking on the dba site rather than the general programming site; https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try to change the index key :

```sql
ALTER TABLE comment_field_data
  DROP KEY `comment_field__created`, 
  ADD KEY `comment_field__created` (`created`, `entity_id`) ;
```

To "encourage" MariaDB to use this new index, you may change your query like this :

```sql
SELECT entity_id 
FROM comment_field_data 
WHERE created > '1970-01-01'
AND entity_id > 0
ORDER BY created LIMIT 300
```

Hope this will help

This technique is named, index covering, which means, the index structure contains all the columns invoked in the query.

Using this index, to execute your query, MariaDB will not have to do extra I/Os reading the data layer contained in the primary key.

Comment: Wow this seems to work!

Comment: are you getting an acceptable response time ?

Comment: Yes it's much faster now ~0.5s. compared to ~30s before. Thank you! I'll keep you up to date.

Comment: maybe can you close your question ?